# How to increase the stack size of vstest.executionengine.x86.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, stack-overflow

We have the problem that one of our C++ unit tests is causing the exception 0xC0000005 (from dmp file -> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access) right when it is executing a method signature (even the body of the method is not executed).
[image]

This is followed by a stack overflow exception. I think this is the actual problem.
[image]

Is there a way to increase the stack of vstest?

EDIT: Here the minidump: [minidump](https://expirebox.com/download/7a73e789a4381a27b6e6ba1e5eda8403.html)

Comment: You are better off finding the cuase of the memory read that shouldn't be happening. Try to narrow it down.

Comment: Both stack overflow and access violation are indicating a presence of serious problems within your code. You should fix them instead trying to increase stack size.

Comment: In my experience on other systems, the 0xC00000xx suggests the attempted use of an uninitialized pointer, not a stack overflow.

Comment: The access violation happened first and is the serious problem.  That the unit test runner then also keeled over on SO when trying to deal with the mishap, well, that happens.  Test failed, write the bug report and attach the minidump.

Comment: Ok thanks i added the minidup file

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d56d80e0-70f1-4ceb-b9ca-aed66e97a3d6/visual-studio-2012-unit-testing-native-c-crashes-due-to-stack-overflow?forum=vsunittest

It says:
you can try to add the following `REG_DWORD` key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\Agent\MaximumTestThreadStackSize` and then set it to a greater value such as `1000000 (decimal)` to check the result.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. But what was also strange is that "EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\Agent\MaximumTestThreadStackSize" didn't even exist, i had to create the keys.